# Error when installing pip package manager for python 3.8.5

Tags: python, pip

i was trying to install pip on python 3.8.5 even tough python 3.8.5 setup comes with pip, mine is not working I've tried both custom installation and install now methods but it still doesn't work so when i downloaded the get-pip.py file and run it command-prompt(as administrator) it gives this error.
[This is what I've been getting when i try to install it via get-pip.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXbNl.png)

Comment: Hi @Dagim did you install python first

Comment: Also please try to install pip with anaconda prompt not on command prompt

Comment: Hey mate, I tried with anaconda but it's still the same.

Comment: can you add detail of your error with command and picture.